# Create line with glow/neon effect from shapefile (with BlenderGIS) and snap it to raster

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, effects

I'm sorry this is a really beginners question.
So I have a shapefile as in here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ISi20XX8BxSdHCXpB_z450GejczPgf4x?usp=sharing

I import the shapefile with the BlenderGIS Plugin. Now I would like to make this line have a neon-effect. However, I do not even see anything when I render it.

Before Render

[image]

I think two steps are important. The first is to create the mesh. I think this thread is useful for that.

1. Really create the mesh as discussed in here:
   https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/233
2. Use something like the Bloom to get the neon-effect.

However, I am not sure if I am right about this and how to approach these steps particularly.

The thing is I really want to create these glowing lines as in here:

[image]

https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/ptulj9/grand_rapids_mi_result_of_lidar_in_blender/

And as a last step (which is even more confusing to me), I'd like to put the shapefile on top of a raster layer such that it just lays above it. I think there is a snapping option but I am not sure if this is the best idea. There is also the possibility to extract the height values directly from a field within the shapefile. But what if I change the z-extrusion for the raster in Blender. I guess than it wont work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you show, it looks like tubes that have an *Emission* shader as material, and the glow we see is actually the light that is projected onto the ground, not a kind of bloom. If you use Eevee, you'll need an *Irradiance Volume* to create such an effect, as *Emission* doesn't project any light in Eevee. That said you can still use the *Bloom* option to add more effect (it's in the *Render* tab). Also you'll need to choose *Shadow Mode > None* in the material so that the neon object doesn't project any shadow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! That already helps a lot:) Now I just need to figure out how to import a shapefile and turn it into something like this tube!

Comment: Yes I saw that but I don't know the format of your file  :/